# How to get hostname from Elasticsearch Python module?

Tags: elasticsearch, python-3.5, elasticsearch-plugin

Using Elasticsearch, how do we get the working Elastic host?

```
es = Elasticsearch()
health = es.cluster.health
```

Above statement will print the health of a Elasticsearch host. But how to get the working host from this?

Comment: What do you mean by "working host"?

Comment: say i have a cluster and i need to run a backup. So, i need to pick a host from a cluster.      hlist = "eshost1,eshost2,eshost3"  and  es.cluster.health() will give health of a host from the cluster.  I need the hostname which it pick from the randomisation.

Comment: es = Elasticsearch()
health = es.cluster.health     This will print the health status of ES host. I need that hostname.

Comment: health will not give you the health of any specific node, but the health of the cluster itself. You need to use one of the [nodes stats](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#nodes) function if you want node information

Answer (score 3):

Use `hosts = es.transport.hosts` to get the list of hosts.

You can also use something like:

```
con = elasticsearch.connection.RequestsHttpConnection(**hosts[0])
con.perform_request(...)
```

But even better, you can do something like :

```
es.transport.perform_request('GET', '/_cat/tasks')
```

in order to perform any request on a healthy host from the list of configured hosts.

Answer (score 0):

For a newer version [>=8.x.x] this is possible by accessing `.transport.node_pool.all()`

```py
# get a list of all connections
nodes = [node.base_url for node in es.transport.node_pool.all()]
```